# SQL,How to substring a text, using Char(10)/Char(13) when there is no new line used

Tags: sql

In DB - there is 1 column and 1 row only.

Using query:

```
SUBSTRING(p.notes,0,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10), p.notes ,1)) as name
```

When there are two lines in column all works fine.
When there's only one line, w/o newline or Enter (`CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`), i'm getting `NULL`.

How to fix it ?

Comment: A database with only one value? What's the point...

Answer (score 1):

Simply ensure there is always at least one \r\n by adding one to the end of the string:

```
SUBSTRING(p.notes, 0, CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), p.notes + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), 1)) as name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a case construct:

```
select case when p.notes like '%char(10) + char(13)%' then your code
else p.notes end as name
```

Comment: Thank You. Works Fine :D